# Proving the limit of the $n$'th root of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

Let $p(n)$ be a nonzero polynomial. I want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{p(n)}=1$. It might be useful to that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^d}=1$ when $d$ is fixed.

Comment: What methods have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: Taking logarithm, it is equivalent to show that $$\lim_n \frac{d}{n} \log n = d \lim_n \frac{\log n}{n} =0$$

Comment: It might help to write $p(n) = a_d n^d\left[1 + \frac{a_{d-1}}{a_d n} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{a_dn^d}\right]$ where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it using the squeeze theorem.
Let's write $p(n)$ as $$p(n)=a_{i}n^{i}+a_{i-1}n^{i-1}+\ldots +a_0$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} |p(n)|=\infty$ it therefore exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that for every $n>N$, $|p(n)|>1$ and $\sqrt[n]{|p(n)|}>1$.
So
$$1<\sqrt[n]{|p(n)|}=\sqrt[n]{|a_{i}n^{i}+a_{i-1}n^{i-1}+\ldots +a_0|}\leq \sqrt[n]{|a_{i}|n^{i}+|a_{i-1}|n^{i}+\ldots +|a_{0}|n^i}=\sqrt[n]{(|a_{i}|+|a_{i-1}|+\ldots+|a_0|)n^i}=\sqrt[n]{|a_{i}|+|a_{i-1}|+\ldots+|a_0|}\sqrt[n]{n^i}$$
which converges to $1$.

Comment: Is $a_i$ all positive numbers?

Comment: You're right. So what do I do when $p(n)$ is not $n^d$?

Comment: If $a_j>0$ be the maximum of the coefficients, then $a_in^i+a_{i-1}n^{i-1}+\dots+a_0<a_jx^j+a_{j}x^{j-1}+\dots +a_j$ Now it follows from the squeeze theorem. Now, try when $a_j<0$.

Comment: In that case the polynomial is always negative and $lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{p(n}}$ is undefined right?

Comment: Nope, it is defined, unless I am mistaken. The book I have seems to imply it exists.

Comment: Try to use $e^{\pi i}+1=0$.

Comment: One problem with your proof is that the $a_i$'s can be negative so your inequality does not hold. If you change it to absolute values then it works. You should also consider $\sqrt[n]{|p(n)|}$ instead of $\sqrt{[n]}{p(n)}$ as $\sqrt[n]{p(n)}$ is not defined within the setting of real numbers if $p(n)<0$.

Comment: Great! Also proving for absolute value works for what I need it for. Thanks!

Comment: I took the libery of correcting the proof using the absolute value formulation. Hope it's ok. If you want the old answer back, just click 'Edited...' and 'Rollback'.